# Find out list of who paid more than once in a single months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating one application where every month's member paying the Monthly amount to Company but sometimes happing, application showing error due to if any members entry found in the table more than one times in slip details table.

How can I create a query for find Members list who pay more than one times in single months? Below is table structure for same:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AgentMaster](
    [AgentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentUserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentPassword] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsActive] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ParentAgentID] [int] NULL,
    [ParentAgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BankName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AccountHolderName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IFSC] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BranchName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AccountNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentPhoto] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DOJ] [datetime] NULL,
    [SelectedInDraw] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AgentMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AgentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemberMaster](
    [MemberID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberMobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberDOB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberDOJ] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberGender] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberGenderID] [int] NULL,
    [MemberAddress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberPhoto] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsFreeGift] [int] NULL,
    [GiftID] [int] NULL,
    [GiftName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentID] [int] NULL,
    [AgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CardID] [int] NULL,
    [CardNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SID] [int] NULL,
    [SName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Custom1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Custom2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsActive] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [IsBlocked] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MemberMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MemberID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MonthMaster](
    [MonthID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MonthName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MonthOrder] [int] NULL,
    [ViewOrders] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MonthMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MonthID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SlipMaster](
    [SlipID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SlipNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SlipDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [SlipTotalAmount] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [AgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentID] [int] NULL,
    [TotalMembers] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SlipMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SlipID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SlipDetails](
    [SlipDetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SlipID] [int] NULL,
    [SlipNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentID] [int] NULL,
    [AgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberID] [int] NULL,
    [MemberName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MonthID] [int] NULL,
    [MonthAmount] [int] NULL,
    [LateFine] [int] NULL,
    [SubmittedDateByAgent] [datetime] NULL,
    [ApprovedByAdmin] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ApprovedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [MonthName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Blocked] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SlipDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SlipDetailsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SlipDetails] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SlipDetails_Blocked]  DEFAULT (N'N') FOR [Blocked]
GO
```

Comment: What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: My Ms-SQL Server got crashed due to this. My all created Queries got lost. I am just creating Server once created will update here what I created. In short I have to create list of those member who paid more than one times payment for months

Comment: We're not going to do your job for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no any attempt was made.

Comment: I am trying this way

SELECT
    SlipID, MemberID, MemberName,MonthID, COUNT(*)
FROM
    SlipDetails
GROUP BY
    SlipID, MemberID,MemberName,MonthID
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1 and MonthID=2 
but its showing nothing in results.

Comment: SELECT
    SlipID, MemberID, MemberName,MonthID, COUNT(*)
FROM
    SlipDetails
GROUP BY
    SlipID, MemberID,MemberName,MonthID
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1 and MonthID=2

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ^ Please edit the question to contain those `SELECT` statements @Atharv, and then we can look at re-opening the question. Use the edit feature and make sure the code is block formatted (as per the existing code). I recommend you remove the please-halp begging and urgent begging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, I did it. Below is solutions over my problem

```
SELECT
    SlipID,AgentName, MemberID, MemberName,MonthID, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
    FROM SlipDetails
    GROUP BY SlipID,AgentName, MemberID, MemberName,MonthID
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1  and MonthID=1
```

It's working perfectly as per my needs.